# Abstract method declaration - virtual?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

On MSDN I have found that it is a error to use "virtual" modifier in an abstract method declaration.
One of my colleagues, who should be pretty experienced developer, though uses this in his code:

```
public abstract class BusinessObject   
{
    public virtual void Render(){}
    public virtual void Update(){}
}
```

Also it correct or not?

Answer (score 9):

It can make sense if the abstract class is providing an **optional** point where inherited classes can change the behaviour.

So this way the inherited classes will **not be forced** to implement it but they can if they need to.

Usually this method is called by the abstract class:

```
public AddFoo(Foo f)
{
   // ...
   OnAddedFoo(f);
}
```

Here it makes sense to have `OnAddedFoo` as `virtual` and not `abstract`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the MSDN means you can't use the `virtual` and `abstract` modifier on a *method* at the same time.

You can either do

```
public virtual void Render() {}
```

which means that an inheriting class **can** override this method.

Or you can do

```
public abstract void Render();
```

which means that an inheriting class **must** override this method.

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't abstract methods, they're empty default ones. The difference is you don't HAVE to override them (if you don't, nothing will happen).

It might help your understanding to see them formatted like:

```
public abstract class BusinessObject   
{
    public virtual void Render()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh right, also I cannot use virtual keyword if they had a body, right?

Comment: @Mocco: They *do* have a body, it's just empty. Methods cannot be `virtual` *without* a body.

Comment: if there's no body, they can't be virtual. If there is a body, they can't be abstract

Answer (score 2):

You probably refer to this sentence

> You cannot use the virtual modifier
>   with the static, abstract, private or
>   override modifiers.

This mean that you can not use this in method declaration a method can't be at the same time virtual and abstract.

So the usage that you have presented is fine, because the class is abstract this mean that you can have there some abstract methods (with out implementation that have to be implemented by child class) and virtual method (with implementation that can be override in child class).

Answer (score 0):

Follwing code means that you **must** ovveride this method in inherited class and you can't put some logic in abstract method body:

```
public abstract void Render();
```

But if you declare virtual method you can put some logic inside it and **can** ovveride

```
public virtual void Render()
{
     // you can put some default logic here       
}
```